# how to view the source code of a inbuilt func in python?? eg:eval()

Tags: python

```
import inspect
lines=inspect.getsource(eval)
```

Here is the error i'm getting :

> TypeError:  is not a module, class, method,
>   function, traceback, frame, or code object

Comment: i want to know whats exactly happening behind eval() func.How its performing string expressions.eg:'22*35*3'

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in functions such as `eval()` are written in C, not Python, so the source code can't be retrieved here.

Comment: so how come i can see the logic behind it ??

Comment: @Parzival [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L922) I believe